# Using jQuery Validate with Select2 for validation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-select2

I have a form with **SELECT2** into it.

Here is what the sample image:

[image: Image Here]

As you can see on the image the error label is not the same as the other error labels.

There are two problems:

1. How can I fix the error label on SELECT2 to make it same with the other error labels?
2. How can I add or remove the validation when the SELECT2 changes its value? (Sorry, I am new to SELECT2)

Here is my code to validated my form:

```
$("#systemcodeForm").validate({
    submitHandler: function (form) {
      
  },
  rules: {
    systemtype: {
      required: true         
    }
  },
  messages: {
    systemtype: {
      required: "Please choose the system type",
    }
  },
  errorPlacement: function(label, element) {
    if(element.hasClass('web-select2') && element.next('.select2-container').length) {
      label.insertAfter(element.next('.select2-container'));
    }
    else{
      label.addClass('mt-2 text-danger');
      label.insertAfter(element);
    }
  },
  highlight: function(element) {
    $(element).parent().addClass('has-danger')
    $(element).addClass('form-control-danger')
  },
  success: function(label,element) {
    $(element).parent().removeClass('has-danger')
    $(element).removeClass('form-control-danger')
    label.remove();
  }
});
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<form class="cmxform" id="systemrightsForm" method="post" action="#">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">System Type</label>
        <select id="systemtype" name="systemtype" class="web-select2 form-control" data-width="100%">
            <option value="">-- SELECT SYSTEM TYPE --</option>
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="systemcode">System Code</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="systemcode" name="systemcode" placeholder="Enter system code" autocomplete="off" maxlength="15">
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
   <div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label" for="systemdesc">Description</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="systemdesc" name="systemdesc" placeholder="Enter system description" autocomplete="off" maxlength="40">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you add complete HTML relevant to that image please ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Please see my updated question

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I have solved number 1. The only problem is how to remove the validation when select2 changes its value

Comment: No problem i have added solution to both now. All working.

Comment: Glad to help - Happy coding :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use native `select2` [change](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events#limiting-the-scope-of-the-change-event) function to watch for a `change` on your select option selection.

As you are using `jQuery` .validate to `validate` the select input so by default `.validate` will not hide the label after `option` is selected.

In order to get the correct `label` we need to use a `global variable` to store the label element and then `remove` that `label` on selection of an `option`.

**Live Working Demo:** (both question solved)

```js
var mySelect2 = $('#systemtype')

//initiate select
mySelect2.select2();

//global var for select 2 label
var select2label

$("#systemrightsForm").validate({

  rules: {
    systemtype: {
      required: true
    },
    systemcode: {
      required: true
    },
    systemdesc: {
      required: true
    }
  },
  messages: {
    systemtype: {
      required: "Please choose the system type",
    },

  },
  errorPlacement: function(label, element) {
    if (element.hasClass('web-select2')) {
      label.insertAfter(element.next('.select2-container')).addClass('mt-2 text-danger');
      select2label = label
    } else {
      label.addClass('mt-2 text-danger');
      label.insertAfter(element);
    }
  },
  highlight: function(element) {
    $(element).parent().addClass('is-invalid')
    $(element).addClass('form-control-danger')
  },
  success: function(label, element) {
    $(element).parent().removeClass('is-invalid')
    $(element).removeClass('form-control-danger')
    label.remove();
  },
  submitHandler: function(form) {

  },
});

//watch the change on select
mySelect2.on("change", function(e) {
  select2label.remove(); //remove label
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<form class="cmxform" id="systemrightsForm">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">System Type</label>
        <select id="systemtype" name="systemtype" class="web-select2 form-control" data-width="100%">
          <option value="">-- SELECT SYSTEM TYPE --</option>
          <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="systemcode">System Code</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="systemcode" name="systemcode" placeholder="Enter system code" autocomplete="off" maxlength="15">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="systemdesc">Description</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="systemdesc" name="systemdesc" placeholder="Enter system description" autocomplete="off" maxlength="40">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

</form>
```